# Websphere JMS Deploy Error

Tags: java

I am trying deploy a application on websphere that I developed on jetty.
Locally, I use activeMQ and the application uses spring profile to change the configuration to use the websphere MQ on the Webpshere.
But at deploy I am receiving the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'postadorDeMensagemDeRespostaEventosSNCore': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate br.com.vr.pedidos.lancamentoeventual.api.integracao.infrastructure.PostadorDeMensagemDeRespostaEventosSNCoreComFila.jmsSaidaTemplateEventosSNCore; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsSaidaTemplateEventosSNCore' defined in class path resource [spring-api-jms.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle' to required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'connectionFactory'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle] to required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 'connectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
The library jms local was in the package.
I just put the scope provided in the maven:

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.jms.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```